# Pulling in image from custom taxonomy with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

So here is what i'm trying to do. I have created a custom taxonomy called "country" and within that custom taxonomy I have categories of different countries like, USA, France, Germany, England and so on. I created a ACF(Advance custom field) Field Group that lets me add a image to each country, I have this called "flag". So when I make a post and I check the country under the custom taxonomy I need to pull that image (flag) associated with that category and display it on my page.

I have seen lots of post on what im looking to do but I cant seem to get any to work. Here is the code im TRYING to use.

```
<?php
$attachment_id = get_field( 'flag', 'country_' . $queried_object->term_id );
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );

var_dump($attachment_id);
?>
<p><img src="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>" /></p>
```

Its bring back a "NULL" and not my image id.

Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong or any advice you and lend me?

Answer (score 0):

have you defined $queried_object?

**EDIT:**
TRY THIS OUT

```
<?php
$term =$wp_query->queried_object;
$attachment_id = get_field( 'flag', 'country_' . $term->term_id );
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );

var_dump($attachment_id);
?>
<p><img src="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>" /></p>
```

Comment: Nope, sorry that did not work. Im a little confused as to what the [0] is doing on the end of $thumb If thats calling the id for the taxonomy that needs to be based on what the user selects and not a pre defined id, you know what i mean.

Comment: Well we are not concerned about that right now. We are looking at the var_dump. Can you do another var_dump for  $queried_object->term_id?

Comment: Also can you replace your get with this just to check if its working, get_field( 'flag', 'country_1' );

Comment: That Dumps all the info from my post, you can see my page here http://www.b-for.com.php53-13.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/archives/events/wtm-latin-america-2015 the top of the sidebar is where the dump is

Comment: get_field( 'flag', 'country_1' ); using that still just comes up as NULL

Comment: Well thats an issue then with your taxonomy. Please confirm by going to the main taxonomy page and look at the url. make sure its 'country'. And also confirm that there is a country with an id of 1. Just hover over them and look at the edit url on the bottom of the browser or just change country_1 to which ever id you can find.

Comment: so i remove the $querierd_object dump and i did not have anything with a id of 1, so i changed it to 50 get_field( 'flag', 'country_50' ); and its now pulling in the flag when I call it directly

Comment: Tryout  the edit, If it doesn't work for you then you will have to go for get_the_terms function. Here is the codex link  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

Comment: yea your edit still just brings back "NULL" sorry, I will check out the get_the_terms and see what I can do with that - Thanks for all the help

Comment: Well i was trying to avoid using get_the_terms as it gets multiple terms and somehow may conflict in the future. checkout this answer, this is much cleaner approach http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20431/how-to-get-taxonomy-term-of-the-current-page-and-populate-queries-in-the-templat

Comment: If you got your problem solved using some of the answers in this comment thread, please add it as your own answer to the post and accept it. That way we can keep the ACF-questions clean and tidy, without unanswered questions (that have been answered).