# Using an ACF image object for a custom taxonomy within an echo block loop

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I can't seem to pull a ACF image object for a custom taxonomy when used in this loop, which is made of echo blocks:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$terms = get_terms( 'product_type' );
$image = get_field('product_type_tax_image');
$hero_image = $image['sizes']['medium'];

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

// The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
$term_link = get_term_link( $term );

// If there was an error, continue to the next term.
if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
    continue;
}
var_dump($hero_image);
// We successfully got a link. Print it out.
echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '" class="product-grid- block" style="' . $hero_image[0] . '">';
echo '<div class="product-grid-inner-txt-wrap">';
echo '<h4>' . $term->name . '</h4>';
echo '<p>' . $term->description . '</p>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</a>';
}
?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

The var dump just returns NULL. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930005/echo-ing-a-custom-field-input-within-an-echo) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704246/pulling-in-image-from-custom-taxonomy-with-acf) but don't seem to help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do all the other fields work? Also, take a look at [this page](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article:

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

To pull a custom field from a Taxonomy Term, you need to add a second item to your get_field function call. Like this:

$image = get_field('product_type_tax_image', $term );

Also, it looks like you're trying to loop through $terms, but you're grabbing the custom field's value outside of your foreach loop, so that should get moved inside that loop, like so:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_type' );


    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    //get $term's image
    $image = get_field('product_type_tax_image', $term );
    $hero_image = $image['sizes']['medium'];

    // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

    // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
            continue;
    }
    var_dump($hero_image);
    // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '" class="product-grid- block" style="' . $hero_image[0] . '">';
    echo '<div class="product-grid-inner-txt-wrap">';
    echo '<h4>' . $term->name . '</h4>';
    echo '<p>' . $term->description . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</a>';
    }
    ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Boom! This worked great (although I had to remove the [0] after the variable). I also forgot to add the final code for outputting the hero-image as a background image, but that doesn't effect Joe's brilliant answer. Thanks Joe!